# Get user browser data from the request

Tags: node.js, sails.js, middleware

In php there is a global `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to get user browser data. Is there a similar function in SailsJS at the moment ?

Comment: Would it be enough to just get the user agent via JavaScript? navigator.userAgent in any browser will get that information.

Comment: Ahhhh. I just think so deep without thinking the simplest thing. Yeah I knew this but never thought of it. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: Np :) I'm going to post it as an answer to the question, this way if others come along they'll be able to find it more easily. If you have time to accept the answer that would be great!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are interested in [User agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) on server side, you can get that data from request's HTTP headers:

- An object with all request headers: `req.headers`
- String with user agent request header: `req.headers['user-agent']` e.g. *Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36*
- String with user agent request header: `req.get('user-agent')` - that works exactly the same way (gives you the same result) as above expression.

**Please note that the header name needs to be `user-agent` (lowercase characters) and not `User-Agent`.**

This sample controller will return JSON with your current browser's user agent

```
module.exports = {

  /**
   * `CustomController.getUserAgent()`
   */
  getUserAgent: function (req, res) {
    return res.json({
      userAgent: req.headers['user-agent']
    });
  }
}
```

Example of JSON response:

```
{
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36"
}
```

Comment: @user3656084 This should be the accepted answer. `request.headers` in [tag:node.js] is equivalent to `$_SERVER` in [tag:PHP].

Comment: Thanks very much for all the answers